# Is it possible in CloudFormation to rerun an action if it failes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I have created a CloudFormation Pipeline.
Some tasks need to be rerun on fail.
Is it possible to set it on CodePipeline Level or on CodeBuild Level?
Below are examples that I use for my setup.

```
    - Name: Build
      Actions:
      ## Creating CodeBuild to execute Terraform Repo in TFE
        - Name: CodeBuildTerraform
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Build
            Owner: AWS
            Version: "1"
            Provider: CodeBuild
          InputArtifacts:
            - Name: SourceArtifactTerraform
          OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: BuildOutputArtifactTerraform
          RunOrder: 1
          Configuration:
            ProjectName: !Join
                           - "_"
                           - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
                             - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                             - "ProjectTerrafom"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, CodePipeline (CD) **does not automatically retry** failed actions. You have to do it manually for each pipeline as explained in AWS docs:

- [Retry a failed action in CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-retry.html)

Comment: Hi @Marcin, tnx for reply. I will do that. One more question. Is it possible to use BuildSpec Yaml file not in git root directory but as a file in the same directory as CloudFormation template file?

Comment: @AndrewRamnikov Yes, I i think you could. Please have a look at [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-codebuild-project-source.html#cfn-codebuild-project-source-buildspec) on how you can try doing this.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible that an AWS glitch could have contributed to the intermittent deployment failures, there could be various other factors at play as well. Deployment issues can be caused by a range of reasons, including network connectivity problems, temporary resource unavailability, misconfigured settings, or even issues with the deployment pipeline itself.

If you suspect that the issue is related to AWS, it's a good idea to check the AWS service status dashboard or any relevant incident reports to see if there were any ongoing outages or disruptions around the time of your deployment attempts. Additionally, reviewing the error messages or logs from the failed deployments might provide more insight into the specific nature of the problem.